# Tweepy: switching Application and User authentications

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I know this question is often asked but I never found a proper answer: does anyone know how to switch between Application and User authentications when the Twitter rate limit is reached?

Tweepy provides the ability to issue authenticated requests on behalf of the application itself using "tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)" / to issue requests on behalf of the user, "tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)" should be used.

I believe I should set "wait_on_rate_limit" to false when calling "tweepy.API", then handle the rate limiting + pagination myself... But I'm not sure about the most efficient way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Final note: I've found [Nir Grinberg's forked Tweepy](https://github.com/nirg/tweepy) but it seems unmaintained.